# For Maven, is there a way to skip all the tests in a package?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

When I running unit tests, I want to skip all the tests in a package, but I need to make sure that tests in other packages work properly.

In short, there are three package now:
**com.felix.a**, **com.felix.b** and **com.felix.c**,
I don't want the test class in **com.felix.c** to be run.

I tried to filter the package through the maven-surefire- plugin, but it didn't take effect.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${basedir}/src/test/java/com/felix/c/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you like to skip unit tests in a package? Why not running them?

Comment: It could be that you want to run them only when a specific profile is activated, for example.

Comment: When I push the code to the gerrit, gerrit will trigger unit tests, but I don't want to run the unit tests in this package while pushing the code, because it is a waste of time, but it will be run by someone else later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the leading `${basedir}/src/test/java/` from your exclude, and it will work, as that is implied by the plugin already. From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), it's also possible to use the fully qualified package name for the (arguably) more legible:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>com.felix.c.*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it helped me!

But I have a confused. Actually, I want to filter unit tests is `com.felix.test.example.DemoTestCase.java` and `com.felix.test.testcases.BaseFunctionTest.java`. It can work when I use `com.felix.test.**.*Test*`, and it doesn't work when I use `com.felix.test.*`.

Can't use "*" to represent a directory? it's doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: It seems that `*` matches any character except the `/` that make up the path. To include subdirectories, `**` must be used. If you only want to exclude two specific tests, it's probably safer and more convenient to use `**/example/DemoTestCase.java`and `**/testcases/BaseFunctionTest.java`.

Comment: `com.felix.test.**` can solve it perfectly. Share with you!